# ImageView changes the Image after two clicks

Tags: android, android-fragments, methods, interface, android-adapter

I have a method in my Fragment(with purpose of changing a Listview image into another image after click). I call this method in my adapter.. now when I click on that Imageview nothing happens .. when I click it again it works ..(This Imageview is a Play and Pause button , so when I click it back to turn it to Play icon I have to Click two times again and so on...) ..

This is my method in my Fragment :

```
 @Override
public void imageButtonOnClick(View v, int position) {
    playPause=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.playPause);
    Product m = productList.get(position);
    playPause.setImageResource(m.getPlayPauseId());
    playPause.setTag(position);
    playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                Product m =(Product) productList.get(pos);
                if (paused) {
                m.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                paused=false;
                }else {
                 m.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
                 paused = true;
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     
        }

    });
}
```

I call it this way in my Adapter :

```
holder.playPause=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.playPause); 
holder.playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
          if (callback != null) {
              callback.imageButtonOnClick(v, position);
          }      
    }
});
```

And this is my Interface and Constructor that is also in my Adapter :

```
public interface PlayPauseClick {
    void imageButtonOnClick(View v, int position);
}
private PlayPauseClick callback;

public void setPlayPauseClickListener(PlayPauseClick listener) {
    this.callback = listener;
}
```

*I've implemented this interface in my Fragment*

**Update**

Product class :

```
public class Product implements Serializable {


@SerializedName("pid")
public int pid;

@SerializedName("name")
public String name;

@SerializedName("qty")
public int qty;

@SerializedName("price")
public String description;

@SerializedName("image_url")
public String image_url;

@SerializedName("date")
public String date;



 private int PlayPauseId;


public int getPlayPauseId() {
    return PlayPauseId;
}

public void setPlayPauseId(int playPauseId) {
    PlayPauseId = playPauseId;
 }
```

Comment: I think you need to initialize `boolean paused;`

Comment: @SelimAjimi  you didn't see my method

Comment: Can you give the code of the class Product? Product may return the same path for the already selected resource if you haven't done a special check over there as @SelimAjimi suggests.

Comment: Where is `paused` initialized ? Is it shared between all the imageViews ?

Comment: @o.akrout  It's in my Fragment where I created my method : private boolean paused = true;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't need to send a call back to Fragment for change the play/pause image then notify. Simple change it inside your adapter like

```
holder.playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Product product =(Product) productList.get(pos);
        if (product.getPlayPauseId() == R.drawable.ic_play) {
            product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        }else {
            product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
        }
        v.setImageResource(product.getPlayPauseId());
    }
});
```

**Update**
In your case, all your logic code is in `Fragment` not `Adapter` so I think you can do like this
Adapter

```
Product product = productList.get(position);
holder.playPause=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.playPause); 
holder.playPause.setImageResource(product.getPlayPauseId());
holder.playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
          if (callback != null) {
              // you need to pass the position, don't need pass the View 
              callback.imageButtonOnClick(position);
          }      
    }
});
```

Fragment code

```
public void imageButtonOnClick(int position) {
     Product product = productList.get(position);
     if(your logic){
          product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
     }else{
          product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
     } 
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I have so many data and conditions in my Fragment that I have to check and pass it in my method in my Fragment .. If I set this directly in my Adapter I don't have access to them